# What is the easiest way to install web-mode on spacemacs?

Tags: emacs, laravel-blade

I am a **emacs** beginner.

I already setup **spacemacs** on **emacs**.

I need syntax highlighting for *laravel blade* template.

How should I do?

Answer (score 5):

You could just add `html` layer into your `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` list.

And web-mode will be configured properly for you.

Comment: Thanks @zilongshanren!

Comment: How do I find this list?